# enviar mensaje al validar que todos los radiobutton esten seleccionados Java

Tags: java

no se como mostrar un mensaje al haber seleccionado todos los radiobuttons del formulario sin necesidad de un boton.
lo que quiero es que cuando todos los rbuttons esten seleccionados envie un mensaje diciendo "ganó"

Comment: ¿Podrías publicar el código que intentaste hasta ahora? Es mucho más sencillo responder, y encontrarás más chances de que alguien se interese si ya hay una base sobre la cual enfocarse en algo concreto. Encontrarás el enlace a **[edit]** debajo de tu pregunta. La idea es que todas las preguntas tengan un [mcve].

Comment: Te refieres a radiobuton o checkbox?